# Derivation of ideal pressure distribution in a Venturi meter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

Derivation of ideal pressure distribution in a Venturi meter

This the flow in a Venturi meter for ideas_n - h_1)$ as a fraction of the velocity head. It can be shown that for ideal pressure distribution-

$$ \frac{h_n - h_1}{ \frac{v_2 ^2}{2g}} = (\frac{a_2}{a_1} )^2 - ( \frac{a_2}{a_n} )^2 $$

For learning purposes, i want to understand the equation and thus want to try to derive the above equation using equation 1 and 2. However I get stuck with what does $(h_n - h_1 )$ mean and etc. how do I start ? Thanks..

Comment: In [making your edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/406817/revisions), you've deleted quite a lot and have made the question rather difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok now see the first equation-

consider the first and the last terms 
$$\frac{v_1^2}{2g} + h_1 =\frac{v_n^2}{2g} + h_n $$
$$h_n-h_1=\frac{v_1^2}{2g}-\frac{v_n^2}{2g}$$ -(1)

Now see the continuity equation-

$$v_1a_1  = v_2a_2$$
$$\frac{v_2a_2}{a_1}=v_1$$  -(2)

and similarly,
$$v_na_n  = v_2a_2$$
$$\frac{v_2a_2}{a_n}=v_n$$  -(3)

substitute values of v1 and vn from equation 2 and 3 in 1 you will get your answer.